# transparency of button is not changed using 'setAlpha'

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a simple application ,in that there is set of 6 buttons. 
when i clicked on one of  these button then the other buttons must be partially transparent. I tried to done that By setting alpha of 5 buttons

`acre_button.getBackground().mutate().setAlpha(155);`

Ui of the application not changed as i expected. i got only 3 out of 5 is get transparent.when clicking on that two button it is slowly changing it's transparency

Thanks in advance

regards,
kariyachan

Comment: i set alpha  155 for Buttons .some buttons background image transparency is not changing(UI is not changing accordingly)

Answer (score 1):

```
Button btn;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_btn);  
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagen);  
    d.setAlpha(60);  
    btn.setBackgroundDrawable(d);  
}
```

This works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: hi . Thank you for your reply. But it makes the whole button completely transparent. What I am looking is putting some opacity (maybe via alpha value) on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Find a button background in your android-sdk directory here: `android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\drawable-mdpi\btn_default_normal.9.png`

You can modify it to make it semi transparent (Please note that this is a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) and you shouldn't change the opacity of the black lines).

Once you have this changed button in your drawable directory you can add this to your code:

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transparentImage));
```

to make it semi transparent and

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(Android.R.drawable.btn_default_normal));
```

to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still hunting for a solution to this:

The method `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d)` is **deprecated** as of **API 16**

Assuming your button's id is `buttonId` and your drawable is named `button_img`,
handle this by using the following within the onCreate method:

```
((Button)(findViewById(R.id.buttonId))).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Drawable d = v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_img);
            d.setAlpha(40);  
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
                v.setBackground(d);
            else
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
            //Then call your next Intent or desired action.

        }
    });
```

Tested and works for me!